# How to prevent google spreadsheed's IMPORTDATA() from interpreting text values as dates/numbers?

Tags: google-sheets, csv-import, cell-formatting

Into a google spreadsheet i want to import a csv data (with `IMPORTDATA()` function) that contains some arbitrary (textual) codes. The function tries to (incorrectly) interpret some of those codes as numbers/dates and setting `text` as cell format for destination cells doesn't help.

So how to prevent `IMPORTDATA()` from automatic text to number/date conversion?

Answer (score 1):

After some trial/error i have found that wrapping the function `IMPORTDATA()` with `ARRAYFORMULA()` seems to prevent this behaviour:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTDATA("..."))
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work (still tried to parse cells), did you do something else?